# Integrating React Web into existing Single Page Web app (incrementally)

Tags: reactjs

Trying to convert an existing Single Page App into React web app, **incrementally**, start by utilizing material-ui Snackbar i.e. http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/snackbar

Assuming existing App resides in `single-app.js`

And trying to add  Snackbar react app , and transpiled it successfully using Babel in server side as `react.app.js`
Below is a inside `react.app.js` (before transpiled)

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import {render} from 'react-dom';
    import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
    import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';
    render(<Snackbar />, document.getElementById('react_container'));
```

I included both `single-app.js` and `react-app.js` within `index.html`

How can I open `Snackbar` coded within `react-app.js` i.e. from `single-app.js` or from script tag (either javascript / babel) within `index.html` -- in order to display message?

Many thanks.

Comment: You probably have to do it in reverse.  Pass a prop (call back function) from single-app to MyMainComponent.  Use that prop to notify MyMainComponent about state changes.

Comment: could you share the code in those two files here.. it would be better for us to help.